# Is there any simple way to make a bidirectional switch using MOSFET chip?

Tags: mosfet

I want to make a bidirectional switch using a MOSFET discrete chip. However the intrinsic diode make it impossible. Is there any simple solution for this?

Comment: An analog switch is two MOSFETs set up as a switch.

Comment: You connect two NMOS's together at the source so they are back-to-back, and drive the gate with a floating drive.

Comment: Possible XY problem. What are you trying to switch and from what signal?

Answer (score 4):

If you use two MOSFETs, then you get a bidirectional switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLhncv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are many ways to get a floating gate drive, depending on your other specifications. For the highest isolation, you can buy an opto-isolator with a photo-voltaic output. If you can cope with a little current on the channel then you can trickle in some bias through a large resistor. There are plenty of other options with transformers or local batteries, which become more or less practical depending on how many channels you want to run.

Comment: Thank you, I'm thinking of making pixel switching TRs for display devices using MOSFETs. So, the floating gate voltage will be supplied from external source.